# How to add a custom tool/command to tortoisehg in linux?

Tags: linux, mercurial, tortoisehg

I am trying to trying to execute a shell command from tortiseHg. My end goal is to run a large shell command with `{REV}` being a parameter. Does anyone know of a way to do this?

I tried using the custom tools option in tortiseHg and it is not working for me.

No matter what I add as the command, It always returns:

```
The command "my command and args" could not be executed.

"No such file or directory"

Please check that the command path is valid and that it is a valid application
```

**How to reproduce:**

1. In tortoiseHg (linux), go to Settings> Tools > New Tool, add a new command.
   Eg. *touch /path/success.txt*
2. Add tool to list
3. Restart thg
4. Click on the tool.

Answer (score -1):

In old prehistoric versions of tortoisehg only hg commands were working. It is said here that now shell commands should work without problem [How to add a custom tool/command to tortoisehg in linux?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374211/how-to-add-a-custom-tool-command-to-tortoisehg-in-linux#comment59255505_19544074)

Comment: This is not correct. Try "notepad.exe" as command and you'll see a notepad window opened.

Comment: You can / should just edit the answer to correct it.

Comment: People, I no longer user tortoisehg so I can test it

Comment: I don't give answers which I didn't test. What I am supposed to do? Write that _maybe_ more recent answers/comments are valid and my is outdated? Ok, I've done that

Answer (score -1):

As lgriZdes mentioned in his answer, custom tool seems to accept only hg commands. Got around this issue by creating an alias in hg which executes a shell command, and calling this alias from custom tools. Let me know if you guys want more detailed info.

Comment: Not true. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19374211/how-to-add-a-custom-tool-command-to-tortoisehg-in-linux#comment59255505_19544074

Comment: The alias approach is valid, but it does not only accept hg commands.

Comment: At least on Windows I can confirm definitively that at least by THG 4.8 arbitrary external programs can be run. However THG apparently runs them in the background, so their output is lost. https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/5502/custom-tools-get-run-in-the-background